# POS System/Merchant Account Integration from Mobile App

Tags: iphone, mobile, point-of-sale

I apologize if my question was already asked and answered previously, but I was unable to resolve my questions.

Basically, I want to move money from someone's CC, bank account, etc.. via my mobile app, to a merchants bank account (or merchants account?) while sending an authorization statement to the merchant's current POS system indicating that the money was successfully processed/moved. In this case, I would have their CC info / bank info on hand to authorize the payment.

What partners/system do I need to accomplish this? I am assuming that the companies that can actually move money through the system are few and far between (seems to be an elite club to prevent money laundering, etc..). Additionally, what steps can I take to integrate into current/older POS systems to push authorizations to them (so that a merchant can get a receipt printed after someone pays via the mobile app)? I am sure this is possible, I just have no idea where to start.

Thank you to anyone who can help. :)

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm facing a similar problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to be very helpful (especially with respect to the business details of dealing with merchant banks), but...  UPOS is a standardization effort in the POS domain.

http://www.nrf-arts.org/content/unified-pos

**Edit:**

> UnifiedPOS, Unified Point of Service is a device interface standard that allows retailers to add new devices to sales floor terminals with minimal, if any, program changes

Sorry.  That probably won't help with payment processing ;)

I'll leave this up here in case you're interested in whole-picture solutions, in addition to abstracting payment providers.

Comment: This could be a first step but.. I could really use some more abstract and/or deeper info on how a system as I explained above could be devised. Thank you Merlyn.